# Glicko 2 Formula

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to learn about [glicko 2 rating system](http://www.glicko.net/glicko/glicko2.pdf) . In that document, there is a formula in step 5, point 2 that says 
$$B = a - k\sqrt{\tau^2}$$
Can anyone explain what is the point of squaring the tau, then getting its root again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sqrt{\tau^2}=|\tau|$$ $ { } $$ { } $$ { } $

Comment: Alright, thanks. I was worried that I missed something out, because the value of tau is supposed to be between 0.3 and 1.2, and they have used || to indicate absolute elsewhere.